# 2020 LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing Impact on IIS Integrated windows authentication

Tags: iis, ldap

I have a question related to the security update (2020 LDAP channel binding and LDAP signing requirement for Windows) described

in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4520412/2020-ldap-channel-binding-and-ldap-signing-requirement-for-windows.

We are using IIS Integrated Windows Authentication for our ASP.Net application. And we are using .NET namespace (System.DirectoryServices) to handle AD connections, but we never pass any AD connection strings from our application, we use the current user context. we anticipate there should not be any impact on our application with this upcoming change.

Would like to confirm if there is any impact?

Would be happy to provide more information if needed.